# Override 'isRedirectSupported' in HttpClient.php?

Tags: extension, core

I've run into the issue of not being able to download extensions because my server fails the test in `isRedirectionSupported()`. This appears to be a long standing issue. I followed totten's advice [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34181.0) and hacked `CRM_Utils_HttpClient::isRedirectionSupported()` to force it to always return true. The downloads then worked without issue.

My question is, is there a way to override `CRM_Utils_HttpClient::isRedirectionSupported()` so that I don't have to apply this hack every time I upgrade civicrm? Is there an existing extension that will do this? Is there some admin setting that will do the override so that isRedirectionSupported() always returns true?